# How to surround a code block with a using statement in ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, refactoring, resharper, coderush

I'm watching Stephen A Bohlen's excellent [Summer of NHibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) series, and have been watching him interact with CodeRush.  I've recently installed ReSharper (I'm a ReSharper newbie), and I'm trying to find some of the ReSharper productivity equivalents that Stephen is demonstrating (tangentially) with CodeRush.

As an example, he demonstrates highlighting a code block that looks like this:

```
ISession session = GetSession();
session.xxx
```

and then turning it into

```
using (ISession session = GetSession())
{
   session.xxx
}
```

He does this by highlighting the block he wants to *surround* with the using statement and then invoking some CodeRush template.  I've been unable to figure out how to do the equivalent thing with ReSharper.  I found the ReSharper Surround command (within the Code command), but when you select the **using** statement, it does surround your highlighted code block, but it does not seem *smart* enough to put the first line within the using clause.  That is, it results in:

```
using () 
{
  ISession session = GetSession();
  session.xxx
}
```

which requires me to move the first line into the using clause.  Am I missing an easier way?

Answer (score 13):

Resharper offers this capability. If your class implements IDisposable, just hit Alt-Enter:

*(removed image dead link "Before")*
*(removed image dead link "After")*

You also have to have your cursor on variable name. Like this: [SShot1](http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/3872/sshot1dd8.jpg) [SShot2](http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/9543/sshot2dn0.jpg) [SShot3](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/9697/sshot3hd5.jpg)

Comment: This isn't working for me?  I only get split declaration and assignment?
namespace DataAccessLayer {
    public class hptest {

        public void Test()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("xx");
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
        }
    }
}

Comment: DirectoryInfo does not implement IDisposable. Any class instance defined in the parameter list of a 'using' keyword has its Dispose() member called at the end of the statement. DirectoryInfo doesn't have a Dispose() member to call, so it can't be in a "using" statement.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are in a situation where the using is already typed and you want to wrap an amount of code with braces... you can do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and then <kbd>7</kbd>.

It will wrap the selection with braces.

Comment: Its 8. 7 stands for {} only (May be a change  in newer version)

Answer (score 1):

I was just watching that episode and wondering if I the same question. Based on the leads here, I found that if I had this code:

```
1        IList<Supplier> returnValue;
2        ISession session = SessionProvider.GetSession();
3        returnValue = session.CreateQuery("select from Supplier s").List<Supplier>();
4        return returnValue;
```

If I put my cursor on the session variable in line 2, and then did Alt-Enter, it would give me:

```
1        IList<Supplier> returnValue;
2        using (ISession session = SessionProvider.GetSession())
3        {
4            returnValue = session.CreateQuery("select from Supplier s").List<Supplier>();
5        }
6        return returnValue;
```

It did get me a couple of times because I did not have my cursor on the variable name, but I did get it to work.

Just a side note, I really prefer watching demonstrations where they are using Code Rush simply because you have visual indicators of what is going on. I wonder if that would get in the way if I was not presenting.

And you are NOT a Resharper Newbie: You are a Resharper Padawan :)

Swampy

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if something is wrong with my ReSharper setup.  When my cursor is on the

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
```

line in the code sample, below, ReSharper only suggests, **Use 'var'**.  If offers NEITHER **Split declaration and assignment** NOR **Put into using construct**??

(Mindaugas -- Your comment is of course correct about DirectoryInfo.  My bad.  Hopefully, this example more clearly illustrates what I'm seeing).

```
using System;

namespace DataAccessLayerTest {
    public class Class1 : IDisposable {
        public void Moo()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Moo");
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Class2 {
        public void m()
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            c.Moo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to have your cursor on variable name. Like this:

http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/3872/sshot1dd8.jpg
http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/9543/sshot2dn0.jpg
http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/9697/sshot3hd5.jpg

It's debatable, if that's really the best decision from Resharper team.

Comment: That did it!  You should post your answer so that I can mark it as answered. :-)

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio 2013 it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
This should bring following dialog

[image]

and then <kbd>A</kbd> for `using`.

Hope this saves you some time.